# update database on dropdown list change event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a drop down list loaded on the page using a javascript (not originally on the page), it's loaded without problems, but then I want to update a database table once the selected value of the dropdown list changes, I'm using this script :

```
<select name = "categ" id="dropd1"><option> .... </option></select>

<script>
    $( "#dropd1" )
    .change(function () {
             var value = this.val();
             $.post('listener_updates.php', {categ: value});});
</script>
```

the listener_update.php contains the script for updating the database :

```
<?php
if($_POST && $_POST['categ']){
connectMaBase();
$sql ='UPDATE produit SET  categorie =  "'.$_POST['categ'].'" WHERE  num_prod ='.$_SESSION['num_prod'];
$req = mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do your option elements actually have a value=""? And what exactly is your problem? Any Errors? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: the expected behavior is to have the database updated, but unfortunately nothing happens, I tried to add an alert(value); to check but no alert box is showing !

Comment: @puelo : yeh the option elements have value I just thought it would be too long to copy the whole code as the drop down list shows perfectely

Answer (score 1):

you didn't ask a question.

anyway, `this.val()` will probably throw an exception.

try `$(this).val()`

**UPDATE:**

try

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropd1', function(){ 
         var value = $(this).val();
         $.post('listener_updates.php', {categ: value});});
});
```

this will create an event listener for dynamically added DOM elements.

Comment: or just `var value = this.value;`

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, I guess the problem comes from the fact that the drop down list isn't originally on the page but rather loaded using a javascript when clicking on an element

Comment: try $(document).on('change', '#dropd1', function(){ // code here });

Comment: I tried it, but it completely altered other javascripts running on the page, now even the script I'm using for loading the drop down list on the page isn't working

Comment: try to put this script AFTER the script that is loading the drop down list. so it will set the event listener AFTER the list is populated (currently it's probably firing on each line loaded to the list). and monitor for JS errors in the background.

Comment: actually I put all my javascripts at the end of the file, isn't it a good practice, will it cause problems ?

Comment: that's a whole different subject to talk about. but i meant, put the "$(document).on(......" script after/under the loading callback, so it will be set only after the dropdown is full.

Comment: and now I made sure the script is placed after the drop down list is loaded, the other scripts work again but this one seems not even being executed !